How do you Define and Call an object
Class Salesman has 3 attributes: salesman, sales_id, and years_worked.
I would like to define bonus, using the years_worked.  I want to add "$" for each year worked.
How do I def bonus()?
The following gives me this error: <function Salesman.bonus at 0x000002602DCAF9C0>
    class Salesman:
        def __init__ (self, salesman, sales_id, years_worked):
            self.salesman = salesman  
            self.sales_id = sales_id
            self.years_worked = years_worked
        def __str__(self):
            print_me =  '\nSalesman: ' + str(self.salesman)
            print_me += '\nSales ID: ' + str(self.sales_id)
            print_me += '\nAnniversary: ' + str(self.years_worked) + "years"
            return print_me
        def bonus():
            bonus = "$" * self.years_worked
            print(salesman, 'earned ', bonus, 'so far this year!')
    def main():
        print("\nWe would like to Congratulate the following Employees", end = " ")
        print("who have hit their workiversary")
        salesman1 = Salesman("Frank", 1234, 10)
        salesman2 = Salesman("Justin", 5678, 5)
        print(salesman1)
        print(salesman2)
        print()salesman1_bonus = Salesman.bonus("Frank", 10)
        print(salesman1_bonus)


Class names are essentially type specifiers; what you need to do is call the function bonus of an object (of type Salesman) and set it to salesman1_bonus.

Since you have already created the salesman1 instance, you can just use salesman1.bonus().  You don't need to refer back to the base Salesman class.

Also, the bonus() method doesn't return anything, so there's no need to assign its result to a new variable.

bonus() needs to have the self parameter first.

Your terminology is a bit odd.  You don't "call an object".  You create an object, and you call the methods OF that object.  You do that via object.method(params).  In your case, the objects are salesman1 and salesman2.  Salesman is a class, not an object.  (OK, yes, it's also an object, but not in the sense needed here.)

You need to give us more details about the error. Are you saying one of your prints produced that string? Is that all of the printed string or have you edited it? Was it a traceback error message? The posted code has a syntax error. You want to post code that you've run yourself that shows the problem.

I think you will pay $ and not only print $ string signs,right?
class Salesman:
        def __init__ (self, salesman, sales_id, years_worked):
            self.salesman = salesman  
            self.sales_id = sales_id
            self.years_worked = years_worked
        def __str__(self):
            print_me =  '\nSalesman: ' + str(self.salesman)
            print_me += '\nSales ID: ' + str(self.sales_id)
            print_me += '\nAnniversary: ' + str(self.years_worked) + "years"
            return print_me
        def bonus(self): # each method need, at leats self
            # def 4th attribute,
            self.bonus = f"${self.years_worked}"
            print(f"{self.salesman} earned, {self.bonus} bonus so far this year!")
            
def main():
    # define two objects
    print("\nWe would like to Congratulate the following Employees", end = " ")
    print("who have hit their workiversary")
    salesman1 = Salesman("Frank", 1234, 10)
    salesman2 = Salesman("Justin", 5678, 5)
    print(salesman1)
    print(salesman2)

    #set and print bonus
    salesman1_bonus = salesman1.bonus()
    salesman2_bonus = salesman2.bonus()

    # call Franks bonus attribute
    print("Frank earned additionally")
    print("Bonus:", salesman1.bonus)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
We would like to Congratulate the following Employees who have hit their workiversary

Salesman: Frank
Sales ID: 1234
Anniversary: 10years

Salesman: Justin
Sales ID: 5678
Anniversary: 5years

Frank earned, $10 bonus so far this year!
Justin earned, $5 bonus so far this year!

Frank earned additionally
Bonus: $10

As a hint or question, why not define all attributes directly with the initialization of the object:
def __init__ (self, salesman, sales_id, years_worked):
    self.salesman = salesman  
    self.sales_id = sales_id
    self.years_worked = years_worked
    self.bonus = f"${self.years_worked}"

In your solution, if you change the year attribute, the bonus will not influenced, until you set the bonus by bonus function call!

Let's say we define an object called my_remote, then we give method/s to the object (my_remote) like: power_off, power_on, ok, and other methods.
If we want to call the method power_off, then use power_off(). If we want to do activities, use my_remote.power_off().
